# ReactJs Create Reusable component with multiple different children

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React and am trying to get up to speed on a few basic concepts, trying to shoehorn it into an existing application (with the intention of slowly converting the entire app into React). So this may be a vary basic question.

I am converting my dialogs first (my app has a bunch of bootstrap modal dialogs), so I am using [react-modal](https://github.com/rackt/react-modal) library to create these dialogs. What I would like to do is make the outer markup for this dialog reusable across all my dialogs. For instance, with this render method:

```
render() {
        return(
            <Modal
                className="Modal__Bootstrap modal-dialog"
                closeTimeoutMS={150}
                isOpen={this.state.modalIsOpen}
                onRequestClose={this.handleModalCloseRequest}
            >
                <div className="modal-content">
                    <div className="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" className="close" onClick={this.handleModalCloseRequest}>
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                            <span className="sr-only">Close</span>
                        </button>
*******INSERT HEADER COMPONENT*******
                    </div>
                    <div className="modal-body">
*******INSERT BODY COMPONENT*******    
                    </div>
                    <div className="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" className="btn btn-default" onClick={this.handleModalCloseRequest}>Cancel</button>

*******INSERT ADDITIONAL FOOTER BUTTONS COMPONENT*******

                    </div>
                </div>
            </Modal>
        );
    }
```

I would like to have the lines that start with the ******** to be variable components that are appropriate (and different) for each dialog.

Obviously, for each dialog, I could just copy and paste this render method into that dialog's class and have hard coded components for that dialog. Something like (for the body):

```
                    <div className="modal-body">
                        <DialogABody />
                    </div>
```

and:

```
                    <div className="modal-body">
                        <DialogBBody />
                    </div>
```

But if I do that, I am then duplicating all the markup for the dialog "chrome" in react.

Essentially, I need some sort of dynamic component?

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on your modal react class you want to do this

```
class Modal extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
            {this.props.header ? <HeaderComponent text={this.props.header} /> : null }
            {this.props.children}
            {this.props.footer ? <FooterComponent text={this.props.footer} /> : null }
            </div>
    }
}
```

then when calling this pass your props

```
<Modal
    className="Modal__Bootstrap modal-dialog"
    closeTimeoutMS={150}
    isOpen={this.state.modalIsOpen}
    onRequestClose={this.handleModalCloseRequest}
    header="My Header"
    footer="My Footer"
>
```

as for the body component part you should pass that as a prop to this dialog class when calling it.

instead of this:

```
<div className="modal-body">
    <DialogABody />
</div>
```

you should have this:

```
<div className="modal-body">
    {this.props.dialogComponent}
</div>
```

which gets passed through on the parent to this class

Comment: That's awesome. On the footer, though, I want to pass in additional buttons (most dialogs are just save and cancel, but some have additional functions) not just text. Can I just pass a component in to "footer"?

Answer (score 1):

Call your model dialog with the wanted components as props.

```
<model header={headerComponent} body={bodyComponent}/>
```

In model render just put {this.props.header} and so on.

Answer (score 1):

for one child component you could simply use `this.props.children`, however, as you have 3 components, you need to put them into separate props:

```
<DialogBody header={<div>header</div>} body={<div>body</div>} footer={<div>footer</div>}/>
```